# Versioning draft Item security gives error "sorry, this item hasn't been shared with you"

Tags: versioning, task-list, approval

I have content approval workflow in Pages Library. I have set the Draft Item security to "Any User Who can edit items".

Now problem is when a user with only Read access wants to view the page (which had been published as a major version in past) He is getting access denied (i.e. Sorry you don't have access to this site). Stating **"sorry, this item hasn't been shared with you"**.

As per my understanding ReadOnly users should see last major version. Please help me.

In addition to above,
I observed this error is appearing only when the workflow is Initiated.

Steps:

1. User edit the contents of page.
2. User save the page and check it in.
3. User hit to Publish this draft
4. User redirected to Info-Path form where he need to enter the Item ID.
5. Approval Task is created in Task list and assigned to a group lets say groupA
6. Once GroupA approves the task, (Here the error comes) it goes to another GroupB.

In the above step 6. when Group A performs it's action Visitor starts getting error ***"sorry, this item hasn't been shared with you"*** . After checking version history, I found that **Approval Status** changes to **Pending**. On Completion Publishing Task Process Here is how the Approval Process starts.

```
If Variable: IsItemApproved equals Yes
    Set workflow status to Approved
    Set Variable: QA Republish Approval to Yes
    If Workflow Context:Association: Start on Item Change equals No
        If Workflow Context:Association: Start to Approve Major Version equals Yes
        or Parameter: Enable Content Approval equals Yes
            Set content approval of item that the task process is running on to Approved (run as the workflow author)
```

Once the above task process is completed, I added more approval task. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Visitors are not able to see last major version published, if the the item is under approval process.

Answer (score 0):

It was my own mistake, I had the status of approved on each approval task process. I later changed it to Pending and this resolved my issue.

```
Set content approval of item that the task process is running on to Pending (run as the workflow author)
```

Hence Just changing from Approved to Pending on all previous approval process and setting the Approved only on Last approval process resolved the issue.